# if cell B4=B1:B2, countif C1:E2=AAA

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

If have 2 tables.

I need the count of AAA for a particular name in Table 2.

Example: I need to count the number of times AAA occurs for Peter.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. What you ask doesn't make sense because Table 2 is empty. Please edit your question and give more/correct info.

Answer (score 0):

In your example formula in *C5* would be like this

```
=COUNTIFS(QUERY($B$1:$E$2,"select * where A = '"&B5&"'",0),"AAA")
```